# Tools to visualize bezier curve on html canvas in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm a big fan of Brett Victor, and I'm curious if there any tools/libraries/frameworks to help visualize how bezier curves (or other shapes) are being drawn to an html canvas element in JavaScript? Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "visualize"?

Comment: If you want to dynamically express curves (or any other data set), you might check out Mike Bostock's excellent d3 library.  The concept behind his d3 library is to separate the data from the way data it's presented--this concept is very freeing to both the data gatherer an to the presentation designer. http://d3js.org/

Comment: @markE, yes! Brett's Victor's talk on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUv66718DII#10_44 starting around 10:44.